# How to move between TableView items by sending QKeyEvent?

Tags: qt, focus, qml, tableview

I have a TableView in my QML file with couple of items loaded in it by providing model to it. I can navigate between the items by arrow keys (UP, DOWN) but i couldn't figure out how to navigate between items by code.

Here is the way i'm trying to send events, but it seems that i'm sending my events to a wrong component:

```
QQuickItem* focusedItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(QGuiApplication::focusObject());

QKeyEvent *event1 = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::Key_Up,Qt::NoModifier);
QKeyEvent *event2 = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease,Qt::Key_Up,Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (focusedItem, event1);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (focusedItem, event2);
```

focus item seems to be a focusScope and it's parent is a null QObject! i've test this with this:

```
qDebug () << "ITEM =>" << focusedItem;
qDebug () << "PARENT=>" << focusedItem->parent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to look for stuff like this is the auto tests of Qt itself. If you look at [`tst_tableview.qml`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/tests/auto/controls/data/tst_tableview.qml#n153), for example, you'll see that the key events are not sent to a particular item. Instead, the target item is given focus beforehand, and the event is sent to the window:

```
table.forceActiveFocus();
keyClick(Qt.Key_Down);
```

So, as a small example:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQuick>

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Controller() :
        mTarget(0),
        mTimerId(0) {
    }

    void setTarget(QQuickItem *item) {
        if (item == mTarget)
            return;

        mTarget = item;

        if (mTarget)
            mTimerId = startTimer(1000);
        else
            killTimer(mTimerId);
    }

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) {
        if (mTarget) {
            QKeyEvent *event1 = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Down, Qt::NoModifier);
            QKeyEvent *event2 = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Down, Qt::NoModifier);
            QCoreApplication::postEvent(mTarget->window(), event1);
            QCoreApplication::postEvent(mTarget->window(), event2);
        }
    }

private:
    QQuickItem *mTarget;
    int mTimerId;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Controller controller;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    controller.setTarget(engine.rootObjects().first()->property("target").value<QQuickItem*>());

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

When a target item is set on the controller, we start a timer which sends a down event every second to the window that the item resides in. If you only have one window, it's not necessary to have the notion of a target; just give focus to the correct item in QML before sending the event.

Then, in **`main.qml`**:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id:  winRoot
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    property alias target: tableView

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        focus: true
        model: ListModel {
            id: libraryModel
            ListElement {
                title: "A Masterpiece"
                author: "Gabriel"
            }
            ListElement {
                title: "Brilliance"
                author: "Jens"
            }
            ListElement {
                title: "Outstanding"
                author: "Frederik"
            }
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "title"
            title: "Title"
            width: 100
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "author"
            title: "Author"
            width: 200
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ta-da]

Comment: Thank you @Mitch :) but i think there is a little typo there, I used this instead and it works as a charm:
`QCoreApplication::sendEvent((QQuickItem*)(m_target->window()), event1);`

Comment: I didnt compile your exact code but without casting my compiler gets mad at me. Btw im using c++11. And could you give me a little explaination on what is window method and how does it help me here? I couldt print the cast of it to QQuickItem* on console.

Comment: It returns the window that the given item is in. Like I said in the answer, if you only have on window, you could just pass that to the controller instead.